# Why does not the click event function return the first value in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function that returns 'a 'value with the following code.

```
$("div.download-area > ul > li > a").click(function(){
    txt = $(this).text()
    console.log(txt)
    a=  txt
})

return a
```

and this function extract banner name under conditions.

```
<div class = 'pdf-area'>
    <ul class = 'pdf list'>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"></span> 'banner name'</a>

        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and in whole html And there are many  tags like this in the whole html.

a return banner name in a tag extract first click

This code works fine except for the first click.

The first click doesn't return any value.

Why not return the first value? And I would be grateful if you could give me the solution.

Comment: Why is simple. You can't return it before the click occurs. At the time you run that line it is undefined. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Show the full function that returns `a`.

Comment: If you want this click handler to get called just after you attached it, you can chain an empty call to `.click()` on your jQuery object, this will trigger the jQuery event without user interaction.

Comment: I'm a beginner. I do not understand your words. Can you give me an example?

Comment: `$(selector).click(function(){...}).click();`. the first `click(function()...)` does **attach** an event handler to the jqery object. An empty call to the same `click()` method does **trigger** the event.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **The first click doesn't return any value**? It is working as it should . Run the below snippet

```js
var a="click on link";
$("div.download-area > ul > li > a").click(function() {
  txt = $(this).text()
  console.log(txt)
  a = txt
})

console.log(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="download-area">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: but, when i return the value of 'a' and the value is received from another function, the first value does not come.

Comment: set a default value for `a` initially and lets see whether it comes first or not? then click the `<a>` to see the text is coming or not?

Comment: I have already set the default value and confirmed it in the console window.However, the first value is the default value without the function.